# function that removes last element from table

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have this code that adds input to table.
I want to make a function that removes the last added row in the table.
Here is the code that I have:

```js
function add() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name");
  var surname = document.getElementById("surname");
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  name = name.value;
  surname = surname.value;
  output.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + surname + "</td></tr>"
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    table,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <form action="">
    <div>
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="name">Surname</label>
      <input type="text" id="surname">
    </div>
  </form>
  <input type="button" onclick="add();" value="Add">
  <input type="button" onclick="remove();" value="Remove">
  <div>
    <table id="output">
      <thead>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Surname</td>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

For example if I enter more rows in my table and if I click on my remove button it will remove the last element that was entered in the table.

Comment: the `rows` property of the table is an array-like object of all the rows. You can index it to get the last one, and then call `.remove()` to remove it. Which part of this is troublesome?

Comment: `table.rows[table.rows.length-1].remove()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.lastElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/lastElementChild) property to remove the last added `tr` tag in the table

```js
function add() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name");
  var surname = document.getElementById("surname");
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  name = name.value;
  surname = surname.value;
  output.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + surname + "</td></tr>"
}

function remove() {
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
output.lastElementChild.remove();
}
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <div>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="name">Surname</label>
    <input type="text" id="surname">
  </div>
</form>
<input type="button" onclick="add();" value="Add">
<input type="button" onclick="remove();" value="Remove">
<div>
  <table id="output">
    <thead>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Surname</td>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```